# requests retry logic but checking each response before performing exponential backoff and retry

Tags: python, python-requests

I currently have the following.

```
self.session = requests.Session()
retries = Retry(total=5, backoff_factor=1, status_forcelist=[429, 500, 502, 503, 504])
self.session.mount('https://',  HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retries))
```

Which works well. We are introducing a process that will return a 503 with a specific body indicating that the application is under maintenance (as opposed to other potential 503 errors).

I want to be able to catch that specific 503 message and short circuit the retry logic and exit/error after the first call if we get back the 503 under maintenance message.

I could of course write my own retry logic but wanted to check here first to see if there is a way to hook into the process and interrupt the retry loop.

We have considered using a different HTTP status code but don't want to go too far off the reservation as many proxies (think large enterprise) may eat some of the non standard HTTP status codes.

Thanks!

Comment: you may have to check source code to see if you can use some hook. Or write own retry logic.